# How do I make timelines called through a loop occur at different times?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, timeline

I am currently writing an assignment for my Java class in which I need to create the class "Simon Says" game (guess colors in sequence). My issue comes where when I attempt to show the second color, it appears at the exact same time as the first color.

My loop to call a method to make the color flash looks like the following:

```
private void GameCycle(ArrayList<Color> colorSequence)
{

    colorSequence.add(generateColor());

    for(int i = 0; i<colorSequence.size(); i++)
    {
        Color colorRef = colorSequence.get(i);
        if (colorRef != null)
        {
            showColor(findRect(colorRef), colorRef);
        }    
    }


    getGuesses(colorSequence);

}
```

and then my code to show the color is the following:

```
private void showColor(Rectangle shapeToChange, Color colorToChangeTo)
{
    toggleVisibility(); //make buttons invisible when displaying a color
    KeyFrame swapColor = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(0), f->{ //Occurs immediately
        shapeToChange.setFill(colorToChangeTo); //change to the inputed color
    });


    KeyFrame swapColorBack = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), f->{ //Occurs after 1 second into the cycle
        shapeToChange.setFill(Color.BLACK); //change back to black
    });

    Timeline anim = new Timeline(swapColor, swapColorBack);
    anim.setCycleCount(1); //Animation will play once
    anim.play();
    anim.setOnFinished(e ->{
        toggleVisibility(); //make buttons visible
    });

}
```

I can add all of my code, but it is fairly long and somewhat sloppy at the moment.

To give an example of my issue: First color show up on start (red), user clicks red button, now red and green show up at the same time.

What I want to change is so that green will not show up until after red has finished. Is there a simple way I can implement this without screwing up the rest of my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are creating multiple `Animation`s that run parallel. You should just create one `Animation` and add all your `KeyFrame`s to it:

```
private void GameCycle(ArrayList<Color> colorSequence)
{

    colorSequence.add(generateColor());

    Timeline anim = new Timeline();
    anim.setCycleCount(1); //Animation will play once

    for(int i = 0; i<colorSequence.size(); i++)
    {
        Color colorRef = colorSequence.get(i);
        if (colorRef != null)
        {
            showColor(anim, i, findRect(colorRef), colorRef);
        }    
    }

    anim.play();
    anim.setOnFinished(e ->{
        toggleVisibility(); //make buttons visible
    });


    getGuesses(colorSequence);

}

private void showColor(Timeline anim, int step, Rectangle shapeToChange, Color colorToChangeTo)
{
    toggleVisibility(); //make buttons invisible when displaying a color
    KeyFrame swapColor = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000*step), f->{ //Occurs immediately
        shapeToChange.setFill(colorToChangeTo); //change to the inputed color
    });


    KeyFrame swapColorBack = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000*(step+1)), f->{ //Occurs after 1 second into the cycle
        shapeToChange.setFill(Color.BLACK); //change back to black
    });
    anim.getKeyFrames().add(swapColor);
    anim.getKeyFrames().add(swapColorBack);
}
```

Comment: All your `KeyFrame`s are at time zero or time one second, though, so they will still all occur at the same time. You need to increment the duration each time the method is called (i.e. pass in something depending on the loop counter, and set the key frame time based on it).

Comment: @James_D thanks for pointing that out - I've never done animation myself and expected the first parameter of the `KeyFrame`s to mean 'milliseconds from the last `KeyFrame`'. I've updated the code accordingly.